# Only one submit button is working from two in a laravel form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

There is one form and two submit buttons in that form. Only one is working and when pressed other , it refreshes the page. Any clue why one is refreshing instead of submitting?

My Blade code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled-btn" title="Generate PO & View" onclick="generatePoModel()">Generate PO & View </button>
<!-- <button type="submit" name="approve" value="approve" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled-btn" title="Generate PO & Send" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#emailModal" id="generatePo">Generate PO & Send </button>-->
<button type="submit" name="approve" value="approved" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled-btn" title="Generate PO & Send">Generate PO & Send </button>

@if($update_purchase_requisition_approval_data['purchase_approval_status'] != 'onhold')
<button type="submit" name="approve" value="onhold" 
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled-btn" 
        title="Hold On Order">On Hold </button>
@endif

@if(App\Helpers\DesignationPermissionCheck::isPermitted('purchase-requisition-approval.delete') &&$update_purchase_requisition_approval_data['purchase_approval_status']
== 'pending')

<button type="submit" name="pending" id="delete" value="{{ $id }}"
        class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled-btn"
        title="Hold On Order">Delete</button>
@endif

<a href="<?= route('purchase-requisition-approval.index')?>"
    class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="Back to users Page">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please format your code. And let me tell you, two submit buttons should not be there for one form.

Comment: There's only one button for one form, can you explain what you want to do? Also, please provide more details to understand your question!

Comment: change type button to submit

Answer (score 0):

chnage button type to submit

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled-btn" title="Generate PO & View" onclick="generatePoModel()">Generate PO & View </button>

<!-- <button type="submit" name="approve" value="approve" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled-btn" title="Generate PO & Send" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#emailModal" id="generatePo">Generate PO & Send </button>-->
<button type="submit" name="approve" value="approved" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled-btn" title="Generate PO & Send">Generate PO & Send </button>
```